# '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "OG7-5c-Gm7-view-xGh-Gb-9hr" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am using a Custom tableView from this source

https://github.com/klevison/KMAccordionTableViewController

This is working fine when I am using tableViewController but when I am using it with viewController and using a table view inside it gives me this error:

```
[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "OG7-5c-Gm7-view-xGh-Gb-9hr" nib but didn't get a UITableView.
```

Comment: It's a subclass of `UITableViewController`, you have to use it with a table view controller.

Comment: is there any alternate way of doing it or fixing it.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *must* use a plain `UIViewController` in the storyboard (instead of a `UITableViewController`, then have a separate `UITableViewController` that can be embedded in the `UIViewController`. To do this, drag a `UIContainerView` from Interface Builder's list of objects into the `UIViewController`'s root view, add whatever constraints are needed, and then control-drag from the container view to the `UITableViewController` to embed it.